# confusion about the "humorous" tag in the Merriam-Webster's dictionary

Tags: word-usage

[image: Chinese-English dictionary entry for bewail labelled literary+humorous]

How do you interpret the "humorous" tag in the Merriam-Webster's dictionary? Especially when other dictionaries don't give the same word "humorous" tag? For instance "bewail" is said to be humorous on M-W while it is not on other dictionaries. For example, if I want to sincerely mourn for someone dead, is it appropriate to say " I bewail him or her"?

Comment: Where exactly does MW label “[bewail](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bewail)”, or *to express deep sorrow for usually by wailing and lamentation*, as humorous?

Comment: @ColleenV Well, it is on my Chinese version. I have edited my question and added the picture.

Comment: I can't find any instance of "bewail" used humorously. However, it's such an old-fashioned word, that people using it today would intend it humorously, probably in a sarcastic way, like, "The teenager bewailed the car she got for her birthday because it wasn't the colour she'd wanted". The word itself doesn't include the meaning of humour.

Comment: Either way, this is a question of what was in the minds of the M-W writer responsible for this entry, so can only be answered with opinion, not with facts or citations, so I'm closing it to new answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They added the humorous tag probably because a lot of contemporary usage of the word is not serious.

It is often used in a sarcastic sense as hyperbole. The example in your picture "She bewailed the fact that he had such terrible table manners" demonstrates that. It is humorous because "expressing great sadness" seems to be misplaced in a matter as small as table manners.

The reason this designation as humorous is not universal is because others probably thought this humor has more to do with the hyperbole rather than the word itself.

In addition, bewailed also gives the meaning of wailing which is to cry out loud about something, and that is not particularly considered normal behaviour.

So, if someone wants to say he mourns someone's death, it is more appropriate to use the word "mourn" or "grieve." If he wants to say "cry," he should use the word "cry."

Comment: Note that it says _literary **and** humorous_.

Comment: Well, if you don't mind me further bothering, what do one say about the other two examples, namely' bewail your fate' and ' Many people bewailed the changes to the historical building.'? So does it mean that 'bewail' can also be used in some serious occasion?